# Jasmine test getting an unexpected result for angular application

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have written Jasmine test using karma load runner for my angular 4 application. I am expecting the method to return false but is returning true for some reason.
Not sure why ?

Test 1

```js
it('should return false because the current item max value is less to the current min value', () => {
    comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{maxSize: 30000000 , minSize: 30000000 , values: [2 , 2]}];
    let isMax: boolean = comp.isMaxValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items , 1);
    console.log(isMax);
    console.log(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items);
    expect(isMax).toBe(false);
  });
```

method

```js
isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Test 2

method : Please note the the first element in the array would contain minSize : 0 and maxSize: 20000000

```
isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
    if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize  ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }



fit('should return true because the current item min value is equal to the previous max value', () => {
    comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{maxSize: 30000000 , minSize: 20000000 , values: [2 , 2]}];
    let isMax: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[0] , 1);
    console.log(isMax);
    console.log(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items);
    expect(isMax).toBe(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use an item in your array instead of the array itself?

```js
let isMax: boolean = comp.isMaxValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[0], 1);
```

Because of this mistake, your method is trying to convert an `undefined` value to an `int`, which results in a `NaN` value. In JavaScript, [`NaN`s are never equal to each other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

This is why it is super helpful to use the type system of TypeScript.

Comment: my first method passes with your suggestion but my second method fails. I have updated the post

Comment: You are going to need to learn some simple debugging skills to work on these issues as it is a vital part of any software developers toolbox. Here is a good blog post to help you work through these types of issues: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Unfortunately i am new to jasmine and not sure how to debug tests. I wish i knew which would help me solve issues

Comment: If you are using `ng test` to run your tests, you should be able to use all of the skills you have to debug code in a browser as it opens up a browser tab. You can use the break points in the Chrome sources tab, make use of `console.log(...)`, or any other method that you use.